# How should I link (public) files to nodes?

Tags: theming, 8, files

I have many resources (mainly PDFs) that need to be imported to my site.  Previously the files would manually be placed in sites/default/files/mydir and linked to the node like this:

```
<a href="/sites/default/files/mydir/mypdf.pdf">Read More</a>
```

This does work, but I am guessing there are probably strong advantages to actually using the content system - perhaps being able to better organize/track/update files.

How do I place files inside of nodes so the file still appears inline with the rest of the content, while actually being tracked by Drupal?

Comment: Are you looking for the best method to set this up, or a way to add all of your existing files to the managed files that Drupal knows about?

Comment: I'm looking for the preferred method to set this up.

Comment: Still unsuccessfully looking for the preferred method to manage and link files inline.

Comment: Sorry Jon, I've been busy and haven't had time to test on this. I do a lot of module development, but most of my production sites remain on Drupal 7 until some of the larger contrib modules are more fleshed out for D8. I have updated my answer with the only solution I could get working in my limited time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: I missed the 8 tag

**Drupal 8.x**

UPDATE 2:

So this got trickier. The only way I was able to accomplish it was using these steps:

1. Add a field to the node, I called mine "Media"
2. Instead of selecting "File" from the dropdown list, I selected "Other" under reference, and "File" on the next page, this creates an entity reference field rather than a file field.
3. Add a file through `file/add`
4. In your node, start typing the filename of the file you've added
5. In the body field, enter this token: `[node:field_media-formatted:0:entity_reference_entity_view:default]`

The token inserts the rendered entity for the reference field into your content, you can edit how it looks (for images e.g.) through the display settings for file types (May require the [File Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity) module), so you can display a link rather than a rendered file.

Someone pointed out in a thread I saw a couple of months ago:

> Drupal 8 is stable with exactly 0 contributed modules installed

That said, moving to Drupal 8 with requirements that fall outside of the scope of core may be premature for someone who isn't prepared to develop their own solutions yet, and this particular solution may change since parts of it rely on contributed modules.

---

Hopefully this will be an appropriate answer in the future

Very similar to how it would be handled in Drupal 7, but because of module availability there are some tweaks. The modules you would need are [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token), [Token Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter), and [File Entity Browser](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_browser).

The steps are the same as below essentially, but I think the token may use the underscore instead of a dash: `[node:field_files:0:url]`.

Also, once the Token module is installed you can see a list of tokens at `admin/help/token`.

**Drupal 7.x**

There are several mechanisms available to achieve this. If you are using a wysiwyg editor (such as CKEditor), they sometimes have plugins available to allow you to add files directly into the content, but based on what you've stated you need, I think possibly the [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media), [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token), and [Token Insert](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_insert) modules would be a good place to start.

The media module provides a file browser and upload mechanism that works with the core Drupal file system, making it possible to reuse files easily in different pieces of content.

The Token module extends Drupal's core token mechanism, and the Token Insert module allows you to use tokens in text fields.

The basic steps would go something like this:

1. Install all 3 modules, make sure you have the core File module enabled.
2. Go to the "Manage Fields" page for the content type you plan to use these files in and add a "files" field.
3. Add the files that would be used in your article to the files field, either through uploading or using the file browser.
4. Reference the files by index in a token in the text field, a list of available tokens are available [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/390482).

This is untested so may require some tweaking, but if the machine name for your file field is "field_files", the link in the text area would probably look something like this:

`<a href="[node:field-files:0:file:url]">Read More</a>`

That would print the link for the first file that is attached to the node.

There will, of course, be some configuration pages you will have to go through for the media module and field settings, but it's hard to give you any direction on those since they are all very much dependent on your particular installation.

Comment: Media and Token Insert have not yet been ported for 8.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't see the 8 tag. If you only plan to use each file once, this can still be achieved with the Token module and a simple file field

Comment: Check out the [Token Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_filter) module

Comment: i've updated my answer

Comment: I installed the modules and the dependencies.  I enabled "Replaces global and entity tokens with their values" in /admin/config/content/formats/.  I can use Devel to see the available tokens and see that '[node:field_public_forms]' contains a list of files used on the page, but I'm unable to select a single value.  Adding anything else, like '[node:field_public_forms:0:url]' is not translated.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: After you said "Drupal 8 is stable with exactly 0 contributed modules installed" all of my modules stopped playing nicely together.  I haven't been able to attempt your latest instructions, but I will accept this answer since the information is so detailed and thorough.  Thank you for everything.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this by using Entity embed in WYSIWYG.

1) "Add Embeded Button" in /admin/config/content/embed

2) Configure button to desired needs

3) Create/configure new desired display mode for "File" in /admin/structure/display-modes/view.

4) Edit node that files will be placed in.  Click new embed button, reference desired files. Set display mode to the newly created display.

The part of the resulting HTML I care about (download link) is nested within 3 divs, so I used a little JS to style it.  I'm leaving Trey's answer as accepted, because tokens would be the better way to do this, but using tokens I couldn't figure out how to select a single value out of a field containing multiple values.